# Is it possible to have one webserver where a certain sub folder comes from a different server?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

My desired scenario:

- www.my-example-server.com - This one comes from server 1 (IIS 7.5)
- www.my-example-server.com/**subfolder** - This one should come from server 2 (IIS 7.5)

I know how to do this if it were different (sub) domains but not if it are sub folders.

**My question:**

Is it possible to set up such a configuration with Windows machines and/or some DNS configurations?

**Update 1:**

Please assume that server 1 and server 2 should have no relation at all, i.e. server 1 could be in another data center than server 2.

My goal is to cut off some high-volume applications (in "subfolder") from our primary domain which host a low-volume application.

**Update 2:**

Since I have to provide the existing folder structure due to legacy applications POSTing to the server (and [redirecting a POST is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)), I would prefer a solution that is transparent to the end user.

Comment: If you want client connections to go to the second server without passing through the first one, this can't be done, sorry; DNS only handles server names, not URLs; you can't send some connections to a server and some others to another one if they are subfolders of the same site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest using subdomains, rather then subfolders if you want to spread the workload to different servers.

Just make A-records for the domain.

Ex:

```
A    www    1.2.3.4
A    app1   1.2.3.5
```

This would make www.mydomain.com point to 1.2.3.4 and app1.mydomain.com to 1.2.3.5.

You might need to create a forwarder in IIS (Server Manager > Roles > IIS > HTTP Redirect) to forward traffic coming from old applications.

Comment: Thanks, @Bart! Subdomains would be my choice, too, if I wouldn't have to support legacy applications. Since they are POSTing to the subfolders, a [redirect isn't possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get).

Comment: You might need to create a forwarder in IIS (Server Manager > Roles > IIS > HTTP Redirect) to forward traffic coming from old applications.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, and you don't need to act on DNS at all; in IIS, you can have a virtual directory (or a site's home directory) point to a network share.

You simply need to set the directory (or site)'s path to the share's UNC path (`\\servername\share`) instead of using a local path on the web server.

Comment: Thanks, @Massimo I think my question is misleading, I'll update for details.

Comment: If you can set up the second server with a different site name, you can use a HTTP REDIRECT in the subfolder of the first site to send clients to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this purely in IIS will be cumbersome; of course, it's trivial in Apache.

If you can use a front-end apache proxy to point to both backend servers, this can be solved cheaply and simply; just set up proxying for the Locations you wish to push to either backend.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it is achievable for a real-world application that does Ajax, HTTP POST, redirects, rewrites and all this stuff inside IIS to be really transparent when being proxied by an Apache server? I have had bad experiences once, when it comes to details like SSL certificates and the like.

Comment: SSL does add some complexities, but basically, if it was possible without convoluted tricks before proxying, it will work with proxying too.

Comment: Of course if you're going to use a proxy then IIS, Apache or any other server come out even.

Comment: IIS has native proxy capabilities now ?